# Implement Decorator Pattern in Powershell

Tags: powershell, design-patterns, parameter-passing, decorator, parameter-splatting

I have my custom function **f** which runs some stuff then calls a predefined function **Invoke-WebRequest**

I want to make **f** accepts all the arguments that **Invoke-WebRequest** does, and pass those arguments to **Invoke-WebRequest** later.

```
 f --UseBasicParsing -Uri https://google.com -UseBasicParsing  -Body @{'name'='user'} -ErrorOnAction Stop
 # Some processing is made
 # then, the following is executed
 Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://google.com -UseBasicParsing -Body @{'name'='user'} -ErrorOnAction Stop
```

Is there a fast way to achieve this? (Instead of declaring all the possible parameters in **f**)

Comment: `function f {Invoke-WebRequest @PSBoundParameters}`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: If `f` doesn't declare any parameters, you need `function f { Invoke-WebRequest @Args }`

Answer (score 3):

Although it's not the same as not declaring the parameters, you can generate the declarations by generating a proxy command:

```
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Command Invoke-WebRequest))
```

The result is going to look like this:

```
[CmdletBinding(HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217035')]
param(
    [switch]
    ${UseBasicParsing},

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [uri]
    ${Uri},

    [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession]
    ${WebSession},

    [Alias('SV')]
    [string]
    ${SessionVariable},

    [pscredential]
    [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
    ${Credential},

    [switch]
    ${UseDefaultCredentials},

    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    ${CertificateThumbprint},

    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [X509Certificate]
    ${Certificate},

    [string]
    ${UserAgent},

    [switch]
    ${DisableKeepAlive},

    [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
    [int]
    ${TimeoutSec},

    [System.Collections.IDictionary]
    ${Headers},

    [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
    [int]
    ${MaximumRedirection},

    [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestMethod]
    ${Method},

    [uri]
    ${Proxy},

    [pscredential]
    [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
    ${ProxyCredential},

    [switch]
    ${ProxyUseDefaultCredentials},

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [System.Object]
    ${Body},

    [string]
    ${ContentType},

    [ValidateSet('chunked','compress','deflate','gzip','identity')]
    [string]
    ${TransferEncoding},

    [string]
    ${InFile},

    [string]
    ${OutFile},

    [switch]
    ${PassThru})

begin
{
    try {
        $outBuffer = $null
        if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
        {
            $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
        }
        $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Invoke-WebRequest', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
        $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
        $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
        $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

process
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

end
{
    try {
        $steppablePipeline.End()
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}
<#

.ForwardHelpTargetName Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Invoke-WebRequest
.ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

#>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need validation of arguments up front, the simplest way is to pass all arguments - reflected in automatic variable `$Args` - through via [*splatting*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), i.e., as `@Args`:

```
function f { Invoke-WebRequest @Args }
```

Note the limitations of this approach:

- Your function must not be an [*advanced* (cmdlet-like) function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced), because such functions refuse to accept arguments that do not bind to declared parameters.
- While it is possible to declare parameters while still keeping your function non-advanced (so as to declare parameters specific to `f` that shouldn't be reflected in `$Args`), [use of a `[Parameter(...)]` attribute *implicitly* makes your function an advanced one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters), even without an explicit `[CmdletBinding([...])]` attribute.

If you do need to make your function advanced, your best bet is to create a proxy function, as described in [briantist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52907054/45375), which passes values bound to *declared* parameters through via the automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable.